# Can't run postfix on Mountain Lion due to missing system_user_maps.db

Tags: macos, email, server.app

When I start postfix, I see in `/var/log/system.log` the following error:

`error: open database /etc/postfix/system_user_maps.db: No such file or directory`

How should this file be created so that postfix can start properly?

I tried doing `touch` on this file, but I get the error

`` postfix/cleanup[871]: warning: hash:/etc/postfix/system_user_maps is unavailable. open database /etc/postfix/system_user_maps.db: Inappropriate file type or format` ``

Is there a `postmap` command that sets this up?

Comment: That's pretty much a given, considering I'm having a problem, and asking for help.

Comment: The question is missing details (for example what have you tried), to be interesting enough for someone to spend time answering it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to not only `touch /etc/postfix/system_user_maps` but also run `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/system_user_maps` to create `/etc/postfix/system_user_maps.db`. Then postfix will start up.